# how to restore using system backup if restore point is not created

Tags: backup, 16.10

Hello i am new to ubuntu. I have ubuntu16.10 fully installed on my laptop. I take a backup and created .iso of system using system backup software,but forget to create restore point and deleted all the partitions of my ubuntu. Now the problem is,as i mentioned how can i restore it without any restore point.

Please help me guys i have very important data in that backup/.iso file.
Thanks in advance.